# How do i upload an image into database as base64 in django?

Tags: python, django, base64

This is my Code. Model Form And View........

```
   class Home(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        image = models.FileField()
        content = models.CharField(max_length=5000000)  
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        is_deleted = models.BooleanField()
    
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'home'  #model


    class HomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Home                
            fields = '__all__'
            title = forms.CharField(label="title")
            image = forms.FileField(label="image")
            content = forms.CharField(label="content") #form
    
    def HomePage(request):
        home = Home.objects.order_by('-id')
        form = HomeForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # print(request.POST)
            form = HomeForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
            if form.is_valid():         
                    image = form.cleaned_data['image']
                    b64_img = base64.b64encode(image.file.read())             
                    form.save() #model
```

Please What am i doing wrong?
How do i upload an image into database as base64 in django ??

Comment: Upload one image to the database is not a good practice.

Comment: You can save images & videos in media folder rather than saving their base64 code in database and to access them just use the saved path in a url format prefixed with media path - `/media/{{filepath}}`.

Comment: Hi Daniel! Welcome to stack overflow! It would probably be if you elaborated a little on the actual problem/error/type of failure. The code example is fine, but what exactly fails? Are there any error messages, etc. Try to be a little more elaborate. Good luck!

Comment: it doesnt show any error but it does not not save the image as base64, it just saves it as normal django filefield